# Dynamically append href with new li using an API

Tags: jquery, append

Was wandering how to add a dynamically changing `href` to an appended `<a>` element when using an API. It's on the line

```
$("#list").append($("<a href='data[3][0]'><li></li></a>").text(data[1][0]));
```

`data[3][0]` gives a site name such as "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China" from a wiki API and doesn't work. Adding e.g. "https://www.google.com" to the `href` works fine. I guess a solution could be to change `data[3][0]` to it's actual value beforehand but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
var title = document.querySelector("#title");
var description = document.querySelector("#description");
var link = document.querySelector("#link");

var myData = {}

$("#search").keyup(function(e){
  var searchTerm = this.value;
  if(e.which == 13) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=' + searchTerm,
        data: myData,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        headers: { 'Api-User-Agent': 'Example/1.0' },
        success: function(data) {
          $("#list").append($("<a href='data[3][0]'><li></li></a>").text(data[1][0]));
          $("#list").append($("<li></li>").text(data[2][0]));        
        }
    });
  };
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anchor tag should not contain a li element as a direct child. [The HTML <li> element is used to represent an item in a list. It must be contained in a parent element. : an ordered list (<ol>), an unordered list (<ul>), or a menu (<menu>).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)

Comment: okay thanks for letting me know. I've amended my code but left as is on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#list").append($("<a href='"+data[3][0]+"'><li></li></a>").text(data[1][0]));
```

Comment: It works thanks! Why do the extra quotation marks and + signs make a difference?

Comment: You needed to concatenate the result with string. thats why we used + sign
for eg 
var name="Nabeel";
var test="My name is "+name;
// the result would be "My Name is Nabeel" it's simple concatenation

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation can quickly become cumbersome. Fortunately jQuery comes with a simple function signature since 1.4:

> jQuery(**html**, **attributes**)
>   **html**: Type: htmlString. A string defining a single, standalone, HTML element
>   **attributes**: Type: PlainObject. An object of attributes, events, and methods to call on the newly-created element.

Which applied to your code gives:

```
$('<a><li/></a>', {href: data[3][0]})
  .appendTo(document.querySelector("#list"))
  .text(data[1][0])
```

But wait .. ! An anchor `<a>` tag should not contain a `<li>` element as a direct child. [The HTML <li> (…) must be contained in a parent element: an ordered list (<ol>), an unordered list (<ul>), or a menu (<menu>)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)

#### In the end your code could be written this way:

```
$('<li><a/></li>').appendTo(document.querySelector("#list"))
  .find('a').attr('href',data[3][0]).text(data[1][0])
```

```js
let data = ['http://nowhere.com', 'Nowhere'];

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
$('<li><a/></li>')
      .appendTo(document.querySelector("#list"))
      .find('a').attr('href',data[0]).text(data[0])
})
```

```css
li, a{color: black}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list"></ul>
<button>Add item to list</button>
```